# Radio button display gray out in google chrome

Tags: html, css, asp.net, google-chrome, cross-browser

I am use ASP.NET 4.5.In my web Application radio buttons display gray in Google chrome and white color in Firefox.When I try to find solution I got following code to overcome this.

```
input[type="radio"]{

-webkit-appearance: radio;
border:none;width:1em;height:1em;
}
```

This is not give me solution.Also change above style with

```
input[type="radio"]{

    -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
```

but by this radio button only display input text but radio button image not displaying.

Can Help me Any one?

Comment: it is unclear what are you asking. Please struggle and write it better and clerly

Comment: I edited my post. Now it's clear?

Comment: It is clearer but not clear. Please confirm that your problem is: "radio buttons display colour is gray in Chrome and white in Firefox". Your attempted solution is the second piece of code. But using this code gives a new problem: the text next to the radio button does not display at all.

Comment: ya my problem is radio button not display same in both browser.And I try both of code piece which i Put here and text is displayed but radio button image not displaying

Comment: To make it more clear you can make a demo in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and show us here.